# How to inspect the hinted yield type of a Python Iterator

Tags: python, python-typing

Given an iterator:

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

def myiterator() -> Iterator[str]:
    raise RuntimeError()
    yield "Hi!"
```

How can I determine programmatically that the yielded type of `myiterator` is supposed to be `str`?

I cannot run the function itself because it depends on hardware that may not be available.

That is, I am looking for a function of the form `get_yield_type(myiterator)` that returns `str` or `"str"` for the example given.